# Update tabBarItem badge using NSNotification is not working (swift)

Tags: ios, swift, nsnotificationcenter

I want to post a notification from my appDelegate in order to updtae the badge number of the tabBarController.

So in appDelegate :

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("addBadge", object: nil)
```

In the viewController :

```
  func addBadge () {


    badgeNumber = badgeNumber + 1

    var tabArray = self.tabBarController?.tabBar.items as NSArray!
    var tabItem = tabArray.objectAtIndex(3) as UITabBarItem

    tabItem.badgeValue  = "\(badgeNumber)"

   }

  override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "addBadge", name: "addBadge", object: nil)

 }
```

It s not working.
Is it because the viewController where i want to fire the addBadge func is not active ?

Comment: Can you break and make sure that the `tabArray` has items? and that `tabItem` is valid?

Comment: I m sure because if I fire my function manually the badge is updated

Comment: I see; usually notifications are fired on a different thread.

Firstly, use `addObserver` in `viewDidLoad`. Secondly, when you post notification, use the main dispatch queue using — 

`dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { // post notification here });` and see if that helps.

Comment: doesn't work unfortunately

Comment: If you can link to your project, I can probably look into it.

Answer (score 2):

Ok found the solution, you have to add the observer in the init :

```
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

     NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "addBadge", name: "addBadge", object: nil)

}
```